# gulp stop/cancel running task

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

How can I cancel/stop a current running task in gulp?

My task:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('js/main.js')
    .pipe(browserify({
        transform: [to5ify]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

It runs in a watch:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});
```

If I change a js file, the task runs, thats nice. But If I change another file while the task is running, the task does not stop and restart. How can I fix this?

The task runs an average of 20s and the described case occurs frequently

Comment: Use incremental builds: https://github.com/substack/watchify

Comment: I'm new at gulp, can you tell me what the correct changes are?

Comment: Watch this: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md